# She shuts down in tears

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I was watching an interview with a woman. At some point she choked up and ended the interview. Then a voice-over said: "She shuts down in tears".

Is the verb "to shut down" used here in the sense of "she was unable to speak anymore" or "she was unwilling to continue the interview anymore"?

Comment: It's not really an idiomatically established usage, but I imagine the intended sense is more along the lines of ***shut down = cease to communicate / interact*** (to ***withdraw*** from further contact, and perhaps also to ***close*** the interview). But even if the speaker knew exactly what ***he*** meant, not every listener would necessarily understand him that accurately.

Comment: Note that it's ***choked up** ([broke down, faltered,...](https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/choke-up))*. But as a slightly more slangy usage, she could ***choke off*** the interview (kill it off, bring an end to it). Anyway, both your guesses are fine, so I'd say you know as much as any native Anglophone about how to interpret any "nuance".

Answer (score 1):

It’s almost like having an emotional breakdown. She was so caught up in whatever she was crying about that she couldn’t do anything else or continue the interview.